# Button and Text input in JS

Tags: javascript, button, text, input

this is in my PHP file:

```
<input style="text-align: center; max-width: 500px; margin-top: 0px;" type="text" placeholder="Paste your links here separated by a space" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Paste your links here separated by a space'" name='links' id='links' />
<!--lilbanner-->
<BR>
<button class="button alt" id="submit" type="submit">
    <?php printf($obj->lang['sbdown']); ?>
</button>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

I want the button to be disabled when the text input is empty, and when the user types text and deletes it, it will be empty again, means button will be disabled again. I have the following code which works exactly as I want to from my other website, but for some reason it doesnt work (empty text input = button..)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.submit').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#link').change(function() {
            $('.submit').prop('disabled', this.value == "" ? true : false);
        })
    });
</script>
```

can you help me out? thanks in advance!

Comment: I didnt replace anything I know, but still it doesnt work

Comment: The easiest finding might be the solution: Your input has id `links` rather than `link` which you used for the change event handler

Comment: Aaaaand: Your button has id `submit` rather than class `submit` which you used when changing the disabled property

Comment: I know I didnt replace the code with my IDS and stuff, but still it doesnt work..

Comment: I don't get it ... you did not change the code according to your HTML and then you are surprised that it doesn't work? If you change `#link` to `#links` and `.submit` to `#submit` it should work. Check http://jsbin.com/taqayirixa

Comment: your button is always disabled..

Comment: In order for `change` to work you will have to unfocus/blur the input text box. If you want to disable/enable the text box while writing you can follow the answer of Piotr Ma'niak

Answer (score 2):

There you go. You want 'keyup' and 'paste' rather than 'change':

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#links').bind('keyup paste', function() {
        $('#submit').prop('disabled', this.value == "" ? true : false);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors was wrong, look the fix:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
      $('#links').change(function() {
        $('#submit').prop('disabled', this.value == "" ? true : false);
      })
    });
  </script>
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/ETJiPg6BKDNkqbGHXCfk?p=preview